# When does a question icon switch from having a white background to having a green background?

Tags: support, design

When does a question icon switch from having a white background to having a green background? Some of the questions I have answered have white background icons and others have green, it seems that green is better than white. How is that determined? [image: Icons are on the left].

This is not only when the answer is accepted. For example, from my home page
[image: Left icon when answer accepted, what about on the right?]

Note the two entries for **On round robin $R^2$ values for three methods**
On the left it has a green box with a one in it, on the right it has a grey box with a 5+ in it.

I am guessing that this latter, right sided grey, or "off white" converts to green when someone marks the question as a favorite, is that so? Maybe try it, and see?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "question icon"?  (Do you see any green backgrounds when you click on the [unanswered](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered) questions link?)

Comment: No, but they are not shown as icons in the unanswered context. Just as a number of people who like/dislike that question. See icons above that appear in the related category or on the users home page.

Comment: It indicates a question for which one of the answers has been *accepted* by the original poster.

Comment: @cardinal For the questions on the left in the second figure above, I think you are correct, but that is not the whole story, see new text.

Comment: Does your question boil down to "why does the same question ('*On round robin...*') have a green box under 'Questions' but a white box under 'Reputation' " ?

Comment: I would like to know that, yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has to do with whether a question has an accepted answer, and/or whether your answer was accepted.

When you look at a list of questions, the icon is filled green if that question has an accepted answer.  Consider these three from the list generated by the [regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regression) tag:

[image]

The first thread, [linear regression with partially known coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231142/linear-regression-with-partially-known-coefficients), has one answer, which has been accepted.  The last thread, [How to calculate bias when we have an estimation using simple linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231117/how-to-calculate-bias-when-we-have-an-estimation-using-simple-linear-regression), has one answer, which has not (yet?) been accepted.

When you look at your reputation page, you will see a filled green icon representing the reputation you gained from having one of your answers accepted.  Here is a section of your reputation page:

[image]

When the reputation gains from August 14th are expanded, you can see that the icon is filled green because you received 15 points from when your answer to [Is there such a thing as an adjusted $R^2$ for a quantile regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222084/is-there-such-a-thing-as-an-adjusted-r2-for-a-quantile-regression-model) was accepted (congratulations).  Note that the reputation you gained from the upvote is not filled green.

---

Regarding the screenshot of your homepage, *On round robin* is green under questions because it is a question with an accepted answer. The square isn't green under reputation because you didn't earn that 5 points of reputation by having an answer accepted (but by having your question upoted).

Comment: I still do not understand how I can have two different colors at the same time for the same question, see above, without their being somehow  treated differently,

Comment: @Carl, what are you referring to, the reputation case? You can see that there were 2 events that led to increases in reputation: your answer was upvoted & your answer was accepted. The former earned you 10 points & the latter earned you 15 more points. The line that lists the acceptance is filled green, but lines that list upvotes aren't.

Comment: Yes, I know. Your home page seems to be formatted differently than mine. Glen_b asked the right question "why does the same question ('On round robin...') have a green box under 'Questions' but a white box under 'Reputation' " ? I am still in the dark.

Comment: *On round robin* is green under *questions* because it is a question with an accepted answer. The square isn't green under *reputation* because you didn't earn that 5 points of reputation by having an answer accepted (but by having your question upvoted).

Comment: Good answer, please include your last comment into your answer posted above so I can accept it as being "THE ANSWER."

Comment: I accepted the answer anyway as you did indeed answer my question, and you have been very polite to do so.